# Default value for name while inject named bean

Tags: java, spring

In spring we could define beans with property name. So we could inject that bean by using @Named annotation.
I have two beans of same type with different name.

```
<bean id="MyBean1" name="first" class="org.example.MyClass">
   ...
</bean>
<bean id="MyBean2" name="last" class="org.example.MyClass">
   ...
</bean>
```

Is there any way to inject one of beans without define name? For example define default value for name if it is not defined while injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User @Primary annotation or `<bean primary="true|false"/>` tag via xml

> Designate a single bean definition as the primary candidate by setting the primary attribute of its  element to true.
>
> Regardless of the Java version, when multiple beans qualify as autowire candidates, the determination of a "primary" candidate is the same: if exactly one bean definition among the candidates has a primary attribute set to true, it will be selected.

Docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#new-java-configuration)